# Is it possible to do an aftersave() on an app_controller.php in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, after-save

Is it possible to do an aftersave() on an app_controller.php in CakePHP?

I want to detect this on the app_controller for global use so I won't redo it on each controller or model.

Thanks,
S

Comment: What do you wish the controller to do after the save?

Answer (score 4):

firstly `afterSave()` is function of cake's model class **not controller**. So recommended solution is to define a general `/app/app_model.php`

```
// app/app_model.php
class AppModel extends Model {

    function afterSave($created) {
         if($created) {
                 // do clean up after insert
         } else { 
                 // do clean up after update
         }
    }
}
```

In your model class

```
// app/models/user.php
class UserModel extends AppModel // <- its extending AppModel
```

This will be executed by all request by `$this->ModelName->save()`

Comment: 'Insertion' and 'updation': when the words 'update' and 'insert' just aren't enough! :)